# Asymptotics on certain number of polynomials

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I want to count number of polynomials $f(x) = (ax - b) (cx - d)$ with $a, b, c, d \in\mathbb{Z}$ such that the each coefficients of $f(x)$ lies in $\{-L, -L+1, \ldots, -1, 0, 1, \ldots, L-1, L\}$ and $a$ and $c$ are relatively prime.

Note that $f(x) = acx^{2} - x (ad + bc) + bd $.

If the coefficient of $x$ was not there and $a$ and $c$ were not stipulated to be coprime, then I know that number of ways to choose $a, b, c, d$ such that $|ac|\leq L$ and $|bd|\leq L$ is $O(L^{2}\log(L)^{2})$. This is because choosing $a$ and $c$ (or $b$ and $d$) is $\sim \sum_{i\leq L}d(i) = O (L\log(L))$.

Since we require $a$ and $c$ to be coprime and $|ad + bc| \leq L$; I naively still expect the asymptotics to be smaller. However, I cannot come up with an argument to justify/rebuke this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approximately, it doesn’t matter. The coprime piece is mostly irrelevant - if both of them are a multiple of $g$, instead of $L log L$ you have $L/g^2 log (L/g^2)$, so you have a lower bound of $L log L - L/4 log L -L/9 log L -L/16 log L ... > .3 L log L$, so it’s just a constant factor bad. Similarly, if $ad$ and $bc$ are opposite signs, then it’s always good. So at least half of such sets work.

Note that there still are some duplicates (ex: if a and b have common factors), so you’d have to be careful to get this rigorously, but generally asymptotically speaking I don’t think it matters.

Comment: That is one way of counting that I had not considered. Thank you so much. I will try to follow your approach and see what I can obtain in a rigorous manner.

Comment: Thinking a bit more on this, my argument can be repeatedly applied to get a,b,c,d all pairwise coprime which is then sufficient for the polynomial to be unique without affecting asymptotics while giving a lower bound. If you are sufficiently careful, you can even get an exact recursive formula for the number.